# YouTube API derived data

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a application which would gather YouTube user's video data and create some meaningful data and metrics to help the creators market their videos better and expand their audience.

The problem is that since December 18, if I'm not wrong, [this kind of practice is forbidden](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/revision-history).

Can someone from Google comment and explain this change? Why can't I create metrics based on YouTube data, even if I visibly communicate that this is not data from YouTube?

For example: I would like to fetch users video description and tell what's the keyword density, how well is it prepared for SEO (in % or something).

And I guess that this new term destroys many businesses which are doing exactly that thing, creating meaningful data based on YouTube API. (Tubular, TubeBuddy, VidIQ).

Please! Anyone?

Comment: Have you checked [Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) for Youtube?

Comment: @noogui Yes, but this API still does not provide data and metrics which I would like to provide deriving YouTube's data.